# Proving that 2 formulations of the Universal Property of Free Groups are equivalent

Tags: free-groups, universal-property

The present question is inspired by an answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4774083/applications-of-category-theory-in-abstract-algebra/4775470?noredirect=1#comment10163096_4775470) question of mine on applications of Category Theory in Abstract Algebra.

One of the answers stated that the universal property of free groups tells us that $Hom(F_n, G) \cong G^n$ where $F_n$ is a free group generated by n elements and G is any group.

I found that the universal property of free groups is usually formulated differently in terms of being able to uniquely extend a given set map $f:S \rightarrow G$ to a group homomorphism $\varphi :F_S \rightarrow G$ given a group $G$ and a set $S$, where $F_S$ denotes the free group on S.

My question is, are the two notions equivalent when $S$ is finite set of cardinality $n$? I think they are and I have a rough idea on how to prove it but I am not too sure if I am on the right track. Here's what I think:

Since $|S|=n$, the image set of each $f:S\rightarrow G$ determines an $n$-tuple in $G^n$, and we can straightway conclude that $|G^n|≥|Hom(F_n,G)|$ as the elements of $Hom(F_n,G)$ are nothing but extensions of all such $f:S \rightarrow G$. Conversely, each $n$-tuple $g \in G^n$ also uniquely determines a set-map $f_g:S \rightarrow G$ such that $f_g(i)=g_i$ and we can then always find a function $\varphi \in Hom(F_n,G)$ which uniquely extends $f_g$. This gives us the result that $|Hom(F_n,G)|≥|G^n|$. Thus, we can clearly construct a bijection between the two. Is this argument correct and is it sufficient to declare that the 2 are isomorphic in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to argue in terms of cardinalities; you seem to be trying to use Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder but we can just write down the bijection directly (and the arbitrary bijection CBS gives us wouldn't work for our purposes anyway since the bijection needs to be *natural*).

If you want to think in terms of a free group on a set $S$ then you can rewrite the universal property as

$$\text{Hom}(F_S, G) \cong G^S.$$

The point here is that $G^S$ is already exactly the set of functions $S \to G$. Now we can uniquely extend such a function to a homomorphism $F_S \to G$. That's the right-to-left part of the bijection. The left-to-right part is restricting a homomorphism $F_S \to G$ to the generators, getting a function $S \to G$. And the universal property says this is a bijection.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but what exactly does $G^S$ represent? I am unfamiliar with this notation/notion of having sets as powers except in the case of power sets. Is it the same as $G^n$ where $|S|=n$?

Comment: @Acharyachakit: it is the set of functions $S \to G$. If $|S| = n$ it can be identified with $G^n$ so it generalizes the notation in that case.